# After name server change, DNS queries on and off

Tags: domain-name-system, ns-record

I migrated the domain www.pantego.com to a different name server. We were using the Enom registrar and their default name servers, but I migrated them to AWS Route 53. I know all records were copied over, but the domain seems to go up and down at random. Sometimes the website works, and sometimes it doesn't. This corresponds to when nslookup works and doesn't work. The previous TTL was two days and it has not been that long yet, however, why does DNS go up and down for my site? Other users report this too. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Dig always works - nslookup (and therefore ping and http requests) don't always work. I did notice that pinging ns1.pantego.com and ns2.pantego.com return the old IPs, but nothing should be using those addresses anyways? Both the old name server and the new name server have the same settings. I will remove the old one when the TTL expires.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a temporary problem, that will be solved when old records expire.

According to Global DNS Propagation Check, all servers return the same IP:

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.pantego.com

Try using "nslookup www.pantego.com" (Windows) or "host www.pantego.com" (Unix) on problematic computers to see which IP they get from DNS.

Do not forget to completely remove the domain from previous DNS servers.

Comment: I hope it is temporary. nslookup www.pantego.com AND host www.pantego.com (unix) sometimes work and sometimes don't. It changes by the second on the same machine.

Comment: Also, see the edit...